# How to determine which methods are not implemented when XCode has warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Sometimes I have a interface that implements several protocols and I'll get a warning from XCode that my implementation is incomplete.

Is there an easy way to determine which methods are "required" but but implemented (without having to put in dummy implementations of all the non-optional methods from the protocol header files)?

For example, I have a warning on this interface but I don't want to have to dig through all the protocols.. obviously XCode knows that some are missing, why can't it just tell which they are!

```
@interface KTThumbsViewController : UIViewController <KTThumbsViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

XCode 4

[image]

Comment: it says `Method Declared Here` If you click on that. it will show you the method declaration.

Answer (score 8):

Didn't find the answer here, unfortunately.  But a bit more digging turned up an answer, in the Issue navigator in the Navigator View.

Open the Navigator view via the View buttons at upper-right:

[image: View Navigator toggle button]

Then open the Issue navigator via the triangle/exclamation mark button at upper-left:

[image]

If you expand your "Incomplete implementation" Semantic Issue with the little triangle at left, you can see the details of XCode's complaint.

Answer (score 6):

Press alt and click on the protocol, xcode will show you where it is defined so you can take a look at the header file. Alternatively in the "issues" tab it will show you which methods you did not implement yet.

Comment: "I don't want to have to dig through all the protocols". The issues navigator just says "Incomplete implementation" - it does not list methods that are not implemented - see screenshot.

Comment: @P1X3L5 dude, check your OWN screenshot, it shows you what you haven't implemented yet, there are 2 items in the list there for that source file showing the SAME issue

Comment: It tells me **SOMETHING** is missing, but not what it is - that is the root of my original question. It turned out to be a method called -(void)didAddPhoto: which is not mentioned anywhere in the screenshot. Yes, it does tell me which protocol I am missing an impl for (and I didn't notice that before so thanks for pointing that out), but that alone can be of pretty limited value - I am looking for a listing of unimplemented methods without having to go back and forth between mt class and the protocol definition.

Comment: Maybe this is what you were missing (I was too) - click the little triangle arrow in the issues tab next to the warning... (by the screenshot you did, but am writing for fellow blind people like me :-p)

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to this

Sometimes "Incomplete Implementation" really means "Mismatch between the function prototype and the implemented function".

For example, if in your .h file you had this:

```
- (NSTimeInterval) SayDigit: (int) score;
```

But in your .m file you had this:

```
- (NSTimeInterval) SayDigit: (int) digit: (NSTimeInterval) time
```

You would get the "Incomplete Implementation" warning.